# How can I add a condition in a function using ddply

Tags: r, function, plyr

I am creating a new variable `mydata_weighted.equity` for my dataset using the following code:

```
mydata_weighted.equity <- ddply(mydata, .(TrackerID), function(x)
    data.frame(weighted.equity = weighted.mean(x$Equity_dummy,
                                      x$Financiers_Unit_Share_Dollar)))
```

This works.

Now, I want to do the same again, but include only those observations for which a special condition is met. Namely, that the value for the variable `signatory` is >0.

I bet that there is a way like

```
mydata_weighted.equity <- ddply(mydata, .(TrackerID), function(x)
  data.frame(weighted.equity = weighted.mean(x$Equity_dummy,
                                             x$Financiers_Unit_Share_Dollar), if signatory > 0))
```

but I just don't figure out how to code it.

Desperatly looking for help as the deadline for my project is getting closer...

Comment: pre-filter your data frame.  `mydata.filtered <- mydata[mydata$signatory > 0,]` then run your ddply() on that data frame.

Comment: Hey @PaulStaffordAllen thanks for the idea, but the filter doesn't work, I get an error:
'Error in `finance[finance$signatory < 0]`:
! Can't subset columns with `finance$signatory < 0`.
✖ Logical subscript `finance$signatory < 0` must be size 1 or 33, not 1048575.'

Comment: You're missing a comma.  The comma with nothing after it shows you are filtering the rows but leaving all columns.

Comment: Ah yes - now it works jsut fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata_weighted.equity <- ddply(mydata, .(TrackerID), function(x){ 
x %>% filter(signatory>0) %>% summarise(weighted.equity = weighted.mean(Equity_dummy, Financiers_Unit_Share_Dollar)) %>% data.frame()
```

It will filter the data then calculate what you want!